# Extending Dictionary with key and value constraints

Tags: swift, swift-extensions, swift-dictionary

I want to extend dictionary and constrain it to specific key type of NSDate with values of type `Array<MyClass>`

MyClass is a swift class with no subclass.

```
extension Dictionary where Key: NSDate, Value: Array<MyClass>{
    func myFunction() -> Int{
        // Some thing useful
    }
}
```

The above code returns a build error:

> Type 'Value' constrained to non-protocol type
>   'Array'

Ok so it seems that it needs to be constrained to a specific protocol, but strangely enough when I constrain Value to:

> extension Dictionary where Key: NSDate, Value:
>   MyClass

The compiler does not complain and the build succeeds. But MyClass is not a protocol. So what gives?

I've managed to constrain it like this:

```
extension Dictionary where Key: NSDate, Value: CollectionType, Value.Generator.Element: MyClass{
    func myFunction() -> Int{
        var count = 0
        for (_, graphicItemArray) in self{
            count+= (graphicItemArray as! [MyClass]).count
        }

        return count
    }
}
```

But this requires a forced cast because I need to get the count property in a Integer form.

So why can't I constrain it explicitly to value type of [MyClass] ?

Comment: Suggestion for your questions: The title could be something more specific to the problem, like *Extending dictionary with type constraint using a Struct*. Also if you remove `OP1ScheduleControlGraphicItem` from your examples and replace it with something like `NSString` or `UIView` (something that already exist) it makes it easier to copy and paste your examples and try them.

Comment: Yes thank you for pointing it out. I'll just put MyClass instead. I think its important to note that its a swift class without a subclass.

Answer (score 1):

Not being able to use a `where` clause with a struct may be an error. Checking the [language reference for where clauses](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GenericParametersAndArguments.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH37-ID406) and following into

```
conformance-requirement → type-identifier­ | ...
```

Seems like [type-identifier](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/type-identifier) should accept a `struct`, even the example they use is `Int`.

This maybe be something to file a bug for.

---

Related to your specific problem, it seems to work if you use [`_ArrayType`](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.0/protocol/_ArrayType/) which is a protocol that `Array` implements and has the methods you need.

```
extension Dictionary where Key: NSDate, Value: _ArrayType ...
```

I am not sure tho if using that kind of internal protocols would flag your app and make it fail Apple review.

Comment: Using _ArrayType allows me to use the "count" property on the array. But as you say the question remains if this is legal. Also, I did not find a way to constrain it to a specific array of items of "MyClass". If no more solutions are posted I guess I'll take your advice and file a bug. Thank you!

Comment: I certainly hope it is a bug. Otherwise it is imposible to have dictionary extension constrained to `Value: String`, which seems rather silly.