# How to constrain extension to Dictionary with String Key and array of NSManagedObjects as Value

Tags: swift, swift-extensions

I would like to add an extension on Dictionary that only applies to a dictionary with Strings as Keys and Array of NSManagedObject as Value

Ideally it would look like this:

```
extension Dictionary where Key : StringLiteralConvertible, Value: [NSManagedObject] {
```

or

```
extension Dictionary where Key : StringLiteralConvertible, Value: SequenceType<NSManagedObject> {
```

If i only set `Value : NSManagedObject`, it works. But not if its an array of that. Does anyone know a workaround for this?

Comment: There is a discussion and a workaround in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32815718/extending-dictionary-with-key-and-value-constraints

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

Ok, this weirdly worked in the playground of Xcode 7.2...

```
extension Dictionary where Key: StringLiteralConvertible, Value: ArrayLiteralConvertible, Value.Element: NSManagedObject {
    func hello() -> String {
        return "World"
    }
}


let a: [String: [NSManagedObject]] = [:]
a.hello()
```

**ORIGINAL:**

I think you could try to specialize the `Array` type in Swift like this: `Array<NSManagedObject>`

So the result will look like this:

```
extension Dictionary where Key: StringLiteralConvertible, Value: Array<NSManagedObject> {
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this will also produce an error: `type 'Value' constrained to non-protocol type 'Array<NSManagedObject>'`